# How to make Responsive Images for mobile experiences

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

UPDATE

---

I have Fullscreen background image.  This creates problems for mobile browsing for the images are large and hi-res.

Next problem is with things like retina display how does a design/programmer prepare to deal with this issue?  I see lot of article about how to switch between images.  But then I get overly confused with pixel density vs resolution. The when and where it is needed and the how and why to target them.

Example:

*Fullscreen background image at 1900x1080 resolution & 72dpi.   For best optimization, How many images should there be per resolution/pixel density?  Furthermore, Given this scenario which  library/plugin/symantics would be best on tackling this situation?

Lastly, If i use media queries to target and switch background images will it download all the images? or just when the requirements have been met?

```
@media (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
background-image:url('paper1024.png');
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
background-image:url('paper1900.png');
 }
```

Thanks stack

---

*//old question didnt wnat to remove it for comment purposes//*

So I'm making a responsive website with fullscreen images.  The problem I've been running across is that the orginal images are far to large for mobile to download.

Being new to responsive design, I had no idea that this was a problem and discouvered it on my own accord.  I read a few article

The best being:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-images-and-web-standards-at-the-turning-point/

My problem is that: I dont believe `<picture>`tag is open to the public?  I cant find any any more info on this.

Does anyone know if this is allowed? Furthermore, more information/documentation on how to use it correctly.

If `picture` is non-applicable.  Is there any "*standard*" persay on making images responsive with out bloating mobile bandwidth?

Comment: This might help http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I'm willing to use it but seems like theres an HTML5 tag. For this I feel that sustainability may suffer if using HiRes.js

Comment: This is a topic that I've heard discussed at virtually every web development seminar I've been to lately, and probably half the blog posts.

Comment: maybe an easier solution (not the best optimized) is using different size files

Comment: but how do i switch between them when detecting mobile?

Comment: Picture isn't going to exist by the looks of it. It's not that it's not open to the public, but that it doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way i did retinafying in my last project:

First set images for desktop in an ordinary css using background-image:

```
#bg {
  background: image-url('wallpaper_desktop.jpg') center top;
  background-size: 1024px 768px;
}
```

Then, I adress mobile phones e.g. iphone:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){
  #bg {
    background: image-url('wallpaper_mobile.jpg') center top;
    background-size: 320px 480px;
  }
}
```

Then it comes to retina image handling. Use an image, doubled in size (see the "@2x" in filename):

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  #bg {
    background: image-url('wallpaper_mobile@2x.jpg') center top;
    background-size: 320px 480px; // Original size
  }
}
```

Since there are also iPads and MacBooks with Retina Displays, we should consider to serve them larger and hi res versions in comparison to hi res phones:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 2048px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  background: image-url('wallpaper_desktop@2x.jpg') center top;
  background-size: 1024px 768px;
}
```

So, usually I'm using 4 versions per image. 2 desktop versions (one with doubled size for retina displays) and 2 mobile versions (also one with doubled size for retina displays)

By the way: There are no additional requests, when using media queries for additional images.

Comment: thanks so much!  I was curious what would you do for full screen <img> tags? would that require javascript/jQuery? or do you have a slick method for that also?